# Laravel Blade View syntax error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

```
@extends('template') <!-- use template from previous slide -->
@section('title')
Home
@endsection
@section('main') <!-- define a section called main -->

<?php
    $sums = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($student as $s) {
        $sum = $s->mc+$s->tc+$s->hw+$s->bs+$s->ks+$s->ac;
        $sums[i] = $sum;
        i = i+1;
    }
    $sums.arsort();
    echo $sums[count($sums)];
?>
```

Trying to insert some vanilla php code into a blade view. I added everything inside the `<?php>` tag. Getting a syntax error:

```
ErrorException in 1ebcdcea94da98aea68c5115912d9e58eae221d3.php line 13:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' (View: /var/www/html/cs3226/resources/views/index.blade.php)
```

Why? Can't see any syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should update your code like:

```
<?php
    $sums = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($student as $s) {
        $sum = $s->mc+$s->tc+$s->hw+$s->bs+$s->ks+$s->ac;
        $sums[i] = $sum;
        $i = $i+1;
    }
    $sums.arsort();
    echo $sums[count($sums)]; 
    ?>
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Yes - I suspect that's the solution: `$i = $i+1;`

Comment: Ah, rookie mistake. Cheers!